# Visual studio с++ бинарная совместимость

Tags: c++, совместимость

У меня есть сторонняя dll, скомпилированная в vs2008. Исходников ее нету. Я хочу сделать приложение, использующее эту dll.
[Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) вроде как написано бинарной совместимости между vs2008 и другими студиями нет.

1. Из-за этого при разработке приложения я должен ограничиться использованием древней vs2008? Или как-то можно выкрутиться? Хочу, например, делать ее в vs2017.
2. Другая ситуация. Если я хочу сделать приложение, которое будет использовать эту dll для получения данных и далее должно отправлять эти данные другой программе, которая скомпилирована уже в vs2015? Как быть с совместимостью в такой ситуации?

Спасибо.

Comment: В недавнюю тему извращений - прокинуть данные через .net. PS: вообще это шутка, но теоретически должно прокатить.

Comment: DLL она и в Африке DLL. Если бы у Вас были объектники или статическая библиотека, то можно говорить о бинарной совместимости/несовместимости. А формат DLL (к чести Микрософт) не менялся со времен Win3.1. Так что функции из DLL (сишные) должны вызываться. Только надо учесть еще какая платформа - 32 бита или 64 бита. Ну, и если в DLL экспортируются не сишные, а С++ функции, то тоже могут быть проблемы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Но ведь по указанной в вопросе ссылке прямым текстом написано "You can't link...dynamic libraries... built by different versions." Пока не понятно

Comment: Действительно написано. Странно, но значит так оно и есть.